# how to get a specific version of a gem from github

Tags: rubygems, github, version

im using rails 2.3 and ruby 1.8.7, I have version .0.1.6 of crack vendored in my project. I would like to get the latest version to see if it solves a parsing issue I am having.

It looks like the latest version is here:
https://github.com/jnunemaker/crack/

and latest version appears to be 0.1.8.

when I try to install: 
sudo gem install jnunemaker-crack -s http://gems.github.com

it gets version 0.1.4 and installs it.

I tried:

sudo gem install jnunemaker-crack --version 0.1.8
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jnunemaker-crack' (= 0.1.8) in any repository

I guess I could just pull the latest code and copy to my vendor directory, but that seems to be a hack.

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github has [stopped building gems](http://gems.github.com/) unfortunately.

There's a [crack gem on rubygems](http://rubygems.org/gems/crack), perhaps thats the one?

Comment: thanks that worked, can you explain what that means in terms of github stop building gems?

Comment: Github used to build gems for projects uploaded to their servers.  They stopped doing this late in 2009.  see https://github.com/blog/515-gem-building-is-defunct and http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/10/github-stops-gem-building -- they are still hosting old gems, which is why you were able to install version 0.1.4 of that gem, but not the newest version.